Access page sources from Google Chrome extension
I'm going to write extension for my browser (for personal use only) and I need access to items from "sources" tab in dev panel (especially images). Is there any way to do that?
I know that it's impossible from js script due to security, but I hope it's possible from plugin. Maybe with extended permissions.

Access how specifically, what will you do with them?

I'm going to download this images. That's all. Inside html page those images are in low resolution and in storage they are in original size.

You can use performance.getEntries() in your content script to extract the URLs, send them to the background script, which will use chrome.downloads API.

Sadly, I can't. I've tried. Links are one-time links.

Devtools uses CDP, which extensions can also use via chrome.debugger API. For example, send Network.enable and listen to Network.responseReceived.
